# How to make my clients sells their own products?

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.1.5. I want to let my clients to create a account, then they can sell their products in my website? Can this be achieved? Looks like now it only has one admin panel (I means only one admin account can edit website)? Can each client have its 'own panel', then they can edit their product by themselves? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to create them an account with limited access?

Comment: Let me explain more. I want to: A magento website, client A can come here, he can create an account to create/edit/delete products what he wants to sale to public customers. Client B also can do create an account to create/edit/delete products what he wants to sale to public customers. Understand? let me know if you need more. Thanks

Comment: Looking for this https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Marketplace.html?

Comment: This one is not free. Any free extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a marketplace type of website? See list of plugins that might help you:

- cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/marketplace
- store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html
- secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace

Otherwise you will do lots of customisations.

Comment: Which one is best?

Comment: I think unirgy is the what I can recommend but it is more expensive. The first 2 are somewhat same.

Comment: unirgy website is down? Cannot access to it

Comment: https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace